# How to add a double tap gesture to video player without loosing the focus of controls?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I tried it by wrapping the

```
return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            child: Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            )
```

with

```
return Stack(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(child: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: (){
                  print('its double tapped ');
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),))
            ],
          );
```

Now I am able to doubleTap, but with a single tap, controllers don't appear, Is there any way I can achieve both things.

With a doubleTap, I can call the like function and with onTap to show the controllers.

the package used above chewie 0.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTapDown: (_) {
              setState(() {
                isMute = !isMute;
                _chewieController.setVolume(isMute ? 0 : 1);
              });
            },
            onDoubleTap: (){
              print('liked');
            },
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              child: Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController,
              ),
            ),
          );
```

on simple onTap on video, it shows the controller, onTap here is not getting override hence

onTapDown is used as an alternative to onTap to mute the video.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how `Chewie` is built but if there is GestureDetector you could change it to something like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () => setState(() => // show_controls,),
    onDoubleTap:() => setState(() => // like behaviour,),
    child: VideoWidget // or whatever is there
}
```

So you can have both listeners on one widget. I think that way `onTap` will be with some slight delay to check if it is not `onDoubleTap`. That way you don't have to put overlay on top of your widget.

If for some reason you want to have this overlay... then the interesting attribute here is `behaviour` as it decides if elements behind will receive events.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/PlatformViewHitTestBehavior-class.html

**Update**
Try changing into

```
GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onDoubleTap: (){
                  print('its double tapped ');
                }
```

**OR**

In the github project, this line:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/video_player/video_player/example/lib/main.dart#L290

It seems that the controls only show when video is in pause state. Its about this value `controller.value.isPlaying`.

Why not to control it in your own GestureDetector ?

```
GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () => setState(() => _controller.pause() ,), //changing here 
    onDoubleTap:() => setState(() => // like behaviour,),
    child: VideoWidget // or whatever is there
}
```

Anyway, hope it you will find answer

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, But the thing is main concern is video-player, not gesture detector. I need to know if there's any show control function for the video player.

Comment: for Chewie specifically or for video_player 1.0.1

Comment: ok, you should provide some decription of package you want to use if its not in official docs, otherwise its hard to know what are you using

Comment: oh my bad :D its is developed by flutter team

Comment: I am using Chewie and what I can see is, by your method the onTap is not detected, but still, on onTap, it shows the controller and its detecting the double-tap behaviour, So in short, I am able to achieve what I   wanted, So thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you did but Im glad you resolved it :) Please accept if it worked or add answer what did you do.